# LACIE Rugged XL 1 TB not recognized (Win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, lacie

I have a Lacie Rugged XL 1TB. I try to connect it via USB 2.0 to my computer with Windows 7 64 bit.

The Disk is running, I can hear it. The nice orange LED is on. But Windows does not even recognize it. It does not appear in the device manager and it does not appear in the Disk Management. 2 days ago my Dad tried it at his XP machine and it worked without problems.

I also tried to find it with diskpart, but it doesn't appear there either.

Any suggestions besides contacting lacie support?

Comment: I assume you tried it on all the usb ports? Do other USB mass storage devices work on that PC?

Comment: I tried the front and back ports, but it didnt work. My webcam, mouse, keyboard, usb-stick DO work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into your BIOS setup and make sure that the drive is listed there (assuming you have USB enabled in your BIOS).

This will help determine if it is your computer that is the problem or Windows.

Also, does it need external power? Make sure that is hooked up properly.

Comment: I will check the BIOS. Yeah it needs external power, but it's properly connected. I can even hear and feel it starting. It's running and has a normal light warm temperature. Gonna check the BIOS now.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the BIOS. I found an additional SATA drive, of which I donÄt know what it is, but it said it has a size of 0 bytes. I don't think that this was the lacie drive, 'cause I connected it via USB and not SATA. I have no idea why this drive isnt't listed ANYWHERE. At least the drive manager should display it. 2 days ago it worked on an XP machine. Are there any known problems with this HD and Win7 x64?

Comment: Since you couldn't find it in the BIOS, you confirmed that it is not a Windows problem. It is your computer in some way. It could be your ports, or your motherboard, or something that is not connecting the drive properly. Having said that, I'm a bit stumped as to why your computer wouldn't like that drive. Do you have other external HDD's you can test? Or even a thumb drive?

Comment: Lol. Just lol. I recently bought a new grapics card. ATI HD5850. Delivered today. I changed my old graphics card, with my new one. Booted my PC. Installing graphic drivers. Playin some games. After I will I turn the HD on, just for the fun of it... And my PC recognizes it! ô_O Problem solved, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Very lol! I have no explanation for you, but I'm glad it works!

Comment: **Update:** It seems that this was just a coincidence. It worked one day, but it didn't the other. I tried it now with eSATA to SATA and that works perfectly. Must be a problem with my USB ports, although there haven't been any problems with other USB devices... I planned to buy a new board next spring anyways. :)

Comment: Either way, glad it works :) Thanks for the update, too! It's always appreciated to get updates!

Comment: I accept this, to close the question.